# Jetpack Compose and code clean up: Move funtions outside of my Composable into a view model or helper class?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, code-cleanup

I have the following code, and would like to clean it up to have better separation of responsibilities.

Do I move the logic outside into a view model, create a class called AccountSummaryFormatter, or should I just throw them into a helperFunction.kt file?
I have an AccountsViewModel.kt file at the top of my component tree, but I feel prop drilling is overkill.

Also, account summary sits near the bottom of component tree.

Here is the code snippet. Its function is to take a certain object type, and generate the relative UI property names for their respective values. I reuse this card multiple times, and didn't want to create multiple compose functions for something that changes slightly.

SummaryTitle is a simple enum class.

```
fun AccountSummary(
    account: Account,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    toggleHUD: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
    currSelection: Int,
    scrollTarget: Float,
    scrollState: LazyListState,

){
    var btnText = if(currSelection == account.name.ordinal) "CLOSE" else "TRANSFER"
    var coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    fun fetchKeyValuePairs(titleList: List<SummaryTitle>, obj: Account): List<Pair<String, Serializable>> {
        return titleList.map{ title ->
            title.title to  when(title){
                SummaryTitle.UNFUNDED -> (obj.total - obj.funded)
                SummaryTitle.FUNDED -> obj.funded
                SummaryTitle.BUDGET -> obj.total
                SummaryTitle.SPENT -> obj.spentFunds
                SummaryTitle.REMAINING -> obj.remainingFunds
                SummaryTitle.UNASSIGNED -> obj.unassignedFunds
                SummaryTitle.TOTAL -> obj.total
                SummaryTitle.INCOME -> obj.total
                SummaryTitle.WAITING -> obj.total - obj.funded
                SummaryTitle.RECEIVED -> obj.funded
                    else -> IllegalArgumentException("Unknown title, failed to process: $title")
            }
        }
    }

    fun getListOfRowItems(account: Account): List<Pair<String, Serializable>> {

        val incomeDisplayProperties = listOf(
            SummaryTitle.WAITING,
            SummaryTitle.RECEIVED,
            SummaryTitle.INCOME,
            SummaryTitle.UNASSIGNED,
        )

        val fixedExpenseDisplayProperties= listOf(
            SummaryTitle.UNFUNDED,
            SummaryTitle.FUNDED,
            SummaryTitle.BUDGET,
            SummaryTitle.UNASSIGNED,
            SummaryTitle.SPENT,
            SummaryTitle.REMAINING,
        )

        val emergencyFundDisplayProperties= listOf(
            SummaryTitle.UNFUNDED,
            SummaryTitle.FUNDED,
            SummaryTitle.BUDGET,
            SummaryTitle.UNASSIGNED
        )

        val loansDisplayProperties= listOf(
            SummaryTitle.TOTAL,
            SummaryTitle.UNASSIGNED
        )

        val savingsDisplayProperties= listOf(
            SummaryTitle.TOTAL,
            SummaryTitle.UNASSIGNED
        )

        return  when (account.name) {
            AccountType.INCOME ->   fetchKeyValuePairs(incomeDisplayProperties, account)
            AccountType.FIXED_EXPENSES -> fetchKeyValuePairs(fixedExpenseDisplayProperties, account)
            AccountType.LOANS -> fetchKeyValuePairs(loansDisplayProperties, account)
            AccountType.SAVINGS -> fetchKeyValuePairs(savingsDisplayProperties, account)
            AccountType.EMERGENCY_FUND -> fetchKeyValuePairs(emergencyFundDisplayProperties, account)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown AccountType: ${account.name}")
        }

    }

    var list = getListOfRowItems(account)
    
    val leftList =  when(list.size){
        2 -> list.slice(0..1)
        4 -> list.slice(0..2)
        6 -> list.slice(0..2)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Non accounted for list length of: ${list.size}. Currently only using summaries with 2, 4 and 6")
    }

    val rightList: List<Pair<String, Serializable>>? =  when(list.size){
        2 -> null
        4 -> list.slice(3..3)
        6 -> list.slice(3..5)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Non accounted for list length of: ${list.size}. Currently only using summaries with 2, 4 and 6")
    }


    Column {...//UI code}
```